# Obtener la clave de un map buscándolo por su valor

Tags: java

Buenas,

No consigo acceder a la clave de un map asciendo por su valor. Tengo un map con la siguiente información:

```
China,zh-CN
```

Esto es para conseguir que me aparezca la frase "Precio base China".

He probado con el siguiente código pero me devuelve el valor `null`:

```
item.getValues().put(Constants.PRICE_NORMAL + " "+ countries.get(Localidad), "-");
```

El valor de `Localidad` es `zh-CN`, con lo cual la frase que obtengo es "Precio base null".

`Countries` es lo siguiente:

`Map<String, String> countries = FileUtils.loadMap("regions.txt");`

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como la documentación explica, `get` es para obtener el valor a partir de la clave. Sería muy complicado si también funcionara al revés (¿qué pasaría si el valor de la clave también apareciera como valor?).

No hay función inversa de `get` (obtener directamente la clave del valor), pero sí puedes recorrer el contenido del `Map` para obtener el valor que falta. Las dos opciones son:

- Usar [`keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()), iterar sobre el `Set`, y para cada valor hacer `get` a ver si el valor devuelto coincide con el que buscas.
- Usar [`entrySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()), que devuelve un `set` de [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html). Cada instancia de `Map.Entry` contiene un par clave/valor. De nuevo, iterar hasta que el valor coincida.

Por supuesto, si esta operación la vas a usar mucho, y suponiendo que no haya valores repetidos, siempre puedes montar tu propia estructura de datos; por ejemplo bastaría que extendieras una clase de Map, añadiendo otro `Map` de forma que, por cada `put(A,B)`, hicieras `put(B,A)` en el segundo. Sólo tendrías que implementar otra función para hacer el `get` inverso consultando el segundo `Map`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabía que no se podía hacer por ese camino, pero he conseguido el resultado que quería iterando.